# Storing the output of a for loop through each iteration

Tags: python

I'm trying to save the output of my for loop for each iteration...for example, here is my code:

```
def encrypt(key):
 for char in (key):
  val = (ord(char)) - (96)
```

for example, if someone entered "lol" through the interpreter my program outputs...

```
encrypt("lol")
12
15
12
```

In this example, I need to store 12,15,12 in memory for use in another function... can anyone help?.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of saving to some temporary value val, save it to a list and return the list.

```
def encrypt(key):
    temp = list()
    for char in(key):
        temp.append((ord(char))-96)
    return temp
```

Comment: wow, that does exactly what i wanted, thank you so much, i didnt think about using lists as we just learned them in class...

Comment: The list comprehension method below isn't bad either, but I don't really think there's any performance gain to using it. This is by far the easiest to understand method... as the linked "List Comprehension" article mentions, list comprehensions are specifically used in cases were map() or a lambda function may be used in order to simplify those.

Comment: If it's necessary to store more than one of these in memory, making temp a value in a dictionary, with lol as the key might be appropriate.

Comment: I am actually not looking for exactly this , but empty list and append gave me an idea of what I am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different methods you could use to do this, but in Python probably the nicest way is to use a list comprehension, like this:

```
def encrypt(key):
    return [ (ord(char)-96) for char in key ]
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

`encrypt('lol')` would then return the list `[12, 15, 12]`.

Comment: Is there any efficiency gain for list comprehensions or is it entirely aesthetic?

Comment: this works pleasantly too ! thanks guys, guess ill have to decide which method to use, Michael's or yours.

Comment: @Michael. I don't really know. I'm fairly new to Python myself. I seem to recall somewhere on my travels that I read that there was a *slight* performance gain, but I can't find it now, so don't take my word for it, I have no idea how they're implemented.

Comment: "List comprehensions perform better here because you don’t need to load the append attribute off of the list (loop program, bytecode 28) and call it as a function (loop program, bytecode 38). Instead, in a comprehension, a specialized LIST_APPEND bytecode is generated for a fast append onto the result list (comprehension program, bytecode 33)." - [Chris Leary](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/) --

Looks like the list comprehensions are slightly more efficient. I rescind my comment about no performance gain.